# GridView Row Command not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have placed a linkbutton in a grid view and it seems to be refusing to fire the row command event when it is clicked.

It weirdly fires when I take the databind out of the !Page.IsPostBack however this isn't much use since it always returns the first row no matter what.

The data in the grid also seems to vanish when after the page has posted back.

My code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvContactHistory" runat="server" CssClass="contactHistory" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvContactHistory_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date:" DataField="CreatedOn" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time:" DataField="CreatedOn" DataFormatString="{0:hh:mmtt}" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Format:" DataField="Type" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="150">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLoadDetails" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Details" CausesValidation="false">
                <i class="icon-down-arrow"></i>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Account account = ClickHelpers.GetSelectedAccount();

        if (account != null)
        {
            SetupContactHistory(account);
        }
    }
}

private void SetupContactHistory(Account account)
{
    var activities = ClickHelpers.GetAccountActivities(account);

    if (activities != null)
    {
        gvContactHistory.DataSource = activities;
        gvContactHistory.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvContactHistory_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Details")
    {
        Guid id = ValidationHelper.GetGuid(e.CommandArgument, Guid.Empty);
        Account account = ClickHelpers.GetSelectedAccount();
        var activity = ClickHelpers.GetAccountActivity(account, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you disabled ViewState somewhere?

Comment: @fanle  Are you using update panel ??

Comment: I can't see anything where viewstate is disabled that might be afecting this. Other postbacks on the same page work just fine, just seem to be this one.
There are no update panels on the grid either sorry.